# When people say "subdomain" do they mean VHosts with similar names, or mod_rewrite mappings?

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, lamp

I'm trying to set a cookie for use across different virtual hosts. Something similar to this has been asked multiple times here:

[Cookies in subdomain doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268391/cookies-in-subdomain-doesnt-work)

[how to access cookies on subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272796/how-to-access-cookies-on-subdomain)

[Cookies And Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723788/cookies-and-subdomain)

[Setting cookies on domain/subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340876/setting-cookies-on-domain-subdomain)

[cross subdomain login with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646842/cross-subdomain-login-with-cookies)

[Cookies and subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108558/cookies-and-subdomains)

They all mention a 'subdomain' but none describe what that is. If I have 2 Apache VHosts like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName home.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/home/
...
</VirtualHost>
```

If I log the user in at example.com and set the --and make sure to say the next word in a deep cookie monster voice-- cookie like so

```
setcookie( 'id', '1234', time()+24*3600, '/', '.example.com' );
```

Can  I get `id` at home.example.com like so:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} \bid=[0-9]+\b
```

Or do these cross domain cookies only work when the subdomains are set up entirely within a single virtual host (presumably with mod_rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely based on the domain name.  The same-origin check doesn't care about the underlying IP.

home.example.com could be:

1. The same as example.com
2. Different
3. Your local box
4. A subdomain set up by an attacker using DNS forgery.

It doesn't matter.  It's still a subdomain.